# Drools runtime error

Tags: java, eclipse, drools

I'm trying to run `Drools` sample ( the HelloWorld sample when creating a new Drools project ), I didn't change anything in the project but I'm getting an error.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:java:org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration'
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:321)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.buildDialectConfigurationMap(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:307)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:192)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.<init>(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:170)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:300)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:228)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.java:34)
    at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:46)
    at com.sample.DroolsTest.readKnowledgeBase(DroolsTest.java:39)
    at com.sample.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The Eclipse JDT Core jar is not in the classpath
    at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration.setCompiler(JavaDialectConfiguration.java:100)
    at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration.init(JavaDialectConfiguration.java:61)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:317)
    ... 9 more
```

I'm running the project in eclipse IDE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like Sid said, the jar is in your eclipse plugin directory.  For my windows box, this is C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.8.2.v20120814-155456.jar

Answer (score 3):

You may need to add the library org.eclipse.core.jdt-version that is on your
eclipse plugins folder to your classpath.

Comment: I tried to google of how would i add the library but i don't know how would i do that? and where can i find that?

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto what Sid and Furrald already mentioned.
Stating just an obvious, but if someone is wondering where they can find the jar for JBoss Dev Studio on a Linux: I have it at

```
<path-to-devStudio>/devstudio/studio/plugins/<name-and-version-of-jdt-core>.jar
```